# Creating a WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: php, javascript

How i can create a custom WSYIWYG editor with custom tags.Actually for editing a xml file.
When a user select a text, a custom tag `<info>` will be added on the selected text.
`<info>Text loaded from a XML</info>`

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for with this vague question? Would it be alright if I delivered a fully working prototype by tomorrow? Or do you just require a pointer in the right direction to get started yourself?

Comment: There are already WYSIWYG editors which can be fully customized. For example: http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: I am creating this editor for adding my own tag. Is their any way to create

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn Javascript, it all build on it.

here is few examples:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/HTML/Building-a-WYSIWYG-HTML-Editor-Part-1/1/

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column11/

Comment: I want to add custom tag before and after of the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

You should kniw the next things:

- Javascript (better some framewprk, for example: jQuery)
- AJAX for anisochronous work with server
- PHP more then middle level.

It is good to develop common structure. With themes import, customizing. It is very hard, because there are a lot of WYSIWYG editors. try to learn theirs code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have other example:

you need get selected text with javascript and then add you tag,

here is script to get selected text:
http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp

then with javascript replace that selected text with '' + 'previous selected text' + ''